# Parse.com Push Notification not working

Tags: java, android, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I am not able to receive push notifications at all. onPushReceieved method in my receiver class is never called.

Here's what my manifest looks like:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
        android:name="com.compName.appName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.compName.appName.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application>
  .
  .


    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.compName.appName.helpers.MyParsePushReciever"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.compName.appName" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application
```

This is the init methods for Parse in my Applications onCreate Method:

```
    Parse.initialize(this, app_id, client_id);
    PushService.startServiceIfRequired(this);
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
```

Here is my Receiver class's onPushReceived method:

```
@Override
protected void onPushReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.i("hereeeeeeeeee === ", "on push recieve");

}
```

I am never able to see that Log. OnPushReceive never gets called. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Check your manifest I think the package names are wrong. I am speaking from experience with parse push.

Comment: could you be more specific? thanks

Comment: change the receiver name from "com.compName.appName.helpers.MyParsePushReciever" to "com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"

Comment: But I'm using my own subclass that extends the ParsePushBroadcastReceiver. Doesn't that mean I should keep the receiver name the way I have it ?

Comment: It didn't. Even if it did, how would my subclass catch the OnpushReceived method?

Comment: Everything looks good to me then

Comment: What are you trying to do with the push anyway I just use it as a notification like in the tutorial

Comment: All I'm trying to do is have the onPushRecieved method log a message in the console. That's it. That's all I want for it to do right now.

Comment: What are your device specs? OS version etc.?

Comment: LG Stylo, running on android 6.0

Comment: Add this line to the application: ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("global" ,new SaveCallback() {

Comment: would I have to make my own "global" channel, or is that default for all devices?

Comment: I was REALLY hoping for that to work. It didn't

Comment: Get rid of the startservice line

Comment: I did, I had replaced it with the call back you mentioned

Comment: this is really weird I have the same device and a working push

Comment: the keys are correct? does Parse say it was sent?

Comment: the parse push dashboard, it says the status is succeeded but under pushes sent, it shows 0

Comment: How can I check to see if the keys are correct? my api and secret key for parse? I don't think any thing else would work if those keys were wrong. parse data base crud methods work

Comment: I also have the get_accounts permission too

Comment: added get account permission, but it did nothing. Besides, I think thats for android os lower than 4.0, I have 6.0 running.

Comment: Ok I think I got it: go into the parse dashboard and go to the registered devices. delete your device.

Comment: Do you mean installations? I went there and deleted the device. still didn't call that onPush receive method.

Comment: And the device registered again?

Comment: Yes it registered again

Comment: I mean under audiences under push

Comment: I had a previous channel, called test. I deleted it, but I have been sending pushes via "everyone"

Comment: Send subscribe to everyone or change to global

Comment: I figure it out, check out my answer below. Thanks anyways though for helping out so much. You DA REAL MVP.

Comment: @TaylorCourtney, you mentioned to check my package name, please comment an answer but also mention check the package name in both the manifest and gradle. You deserve the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your manifest and gradle file, I think the package names are wrong.

Comment: Edit made: include gradle file

Answer (score 1):

I heard about parse.com is going to be off forever

and yes its down officially. 
http://parse.com/

[image]

**EDIT**

As [parse](http://parse.com/) announced their shutdown recently, GCM is the only best option though it won’t comes with an admin interface.
You can follow this awesome tutorial for this.
http://www.androidhive.info/2016/02/android-push-notifications-using-gcm-php-mysql-realtime-chat-app-part-1/

Comment: I am aware of this. But I only need it for demo purposes. I just need to get parse working temporarily.

Comment: :D report parse for this. may be they respond to your report and resume their services for temporary base.

Comment: Don't wait for this. this is not gonna happen. Follow the tutorial to make your own admin interface for this. or you can find an other services like parse.com

Comment: Parse will end in 2017 though. They should be fine for this year on out.

Comment: Oops I didn't noticed the year is 2017, :( sorry for inconvenience

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I had changed my package a long time ago. I had made changes to my manifest, but not in my gradle file.

Shout out to `Taylor Courtney` for continuing in helping me figure it out. He's the real MVP.